# Authenticated referral not able to complete login or registration with initial page load

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Situation:
Using Authenticated Referrals with an app.
We want the click of a timeline post or newsfeed to authenticate the user with our application and when they are directed to our application we want to register or log that user in for the initial display.  No dialog popped up for perms as well for user.

Problem:
When user arrives they do not have the fb cookie as our application server is processing the request.  Also on the return request do not have an access_code or code or facebook id to do further processing.

Per documentation at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/
Auth Token Parameter: If Authenticated Referrals is enabled and when a user authorizes your app through the in-line Auth Dialog, we will pass your app the Auth Token in the format specified here. Available formats:
URI Fragment: if your app is using client-side authentication
Query String: if your app is using server-side authentication. If your app is a canvas app, we will not use this setting and will use the "signed_request" as the response type automatically.

We have it set to query string, but do have a canvas app page that sends the user to our site for invites.

TEST:  using Firefox with firebug, click the link in timeline user doesnt exist on our app and no perms from facebook for our app with that user

so at time we click link in timeline and its loading our page we dont have data to complete authentication but we do get cookies after page is completed and a refresh of page by user will complete the login or registration process.

Comment: I was able to achieve this using the facebook jssdk status check example. [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)